# getTime() in AngularJS , error in new Date(date) in Java Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.notAvailableDayClick=function(val1,date){    
        console.log("day clcik")
        var startDate=$filter('date')(date,'yyyy-MM-dd')
        var endDate=new Date(startDate)
        endDate.setMinutes(59)
        endDate.setHours(23)
    }
```

date is 2015-01-16 
if I do this

```
new Date(date)

Thu Jan 15 2015 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

So I have to go with AngularJS

```
var startDate=$filter('date')(date,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

but now I need `startDate.getTime()`, error occur I think it takes it as a String

Comment: [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Date_Object) expects string parameter in the following form: `MM-dd-yyyy`. `yyyy-MM-dd` form is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option is to use ISO-String, because Google Chrome supports this format: MM-dd-yyyy. In Mozilla this format gives Invalid Date.

```
new Date('MM-dd-yyyy')
```

So using Iso-String in Angular, it can done as follows:

```
new Date($filter('date')(yourdDate,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'))
```

Answer (score 3):

As per angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) the filter returns a `String` in requested format. `Date` [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) accepts ISO8601 formats usually although some browsers support many formats as I remember. Probably your format `yy-MM-dd` is not supported.

I hope the variable `date` is a valid `Date` object, in that case why don't you use it instead of the formatted string you made with angular filter?

```
var endDate = new Date(date);
endDate.setMinutes(59);
endDate.setHours(23);
```

---

Also you have a `Date` constructor that accepts the format

```
new Date(year, month[, date[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

So if what you have in hand is `2015-01-16` you can get midnight of that day with:

```
var startDate = "2015-01-16";
var year = parseInt(startDate.split('-')[0], 10);
var month = parseInt(startDate.split('-')[1], 10) - 1;
var year = parseInt(startDate.split('-')[2], 10);
var endDate = new Date(year, month, date, 23, 59);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the original date to create `endDate` not the angular filtered version

```
var endDate=new Date(date);
endDate.setMinutes(59);
endDate.setHours(23);
```